# Suggest a way to populate database on button click

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am a novice Django programmer, trying to build a basic [e-commerce website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJtxY.jpg). I want to add selected items by pressing 'add to cart' button to the database and load the same home page.
*When clicking  this button is am getting* ***error:*** MultiValueDictKeyError at /
'add_cart'
Please suggest any other good method to the same if required

My template for the button is :

```
<form action="get">
                <button 
                type="submit" 
                class="button1" 
                value="{{ product.id }}" 
                name="add_cart">Add to Cart
        </button>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    products = Products.objects
    product_id=None
    if request.method == "POST":
        product_id = request.POST['add_cart']

    if product_id:
        product = Products.objects.get(id=int(product_id))
        if product:
            product.c_title =product.title
            product.c_description = product.description
            product.c_price = product.price
            product.customer = request.user 
            product.save()
        return redirect(request, 'products/home.html',{'products': products})

    return render(request, 'products/home.html',{'products': products})
```

models.py
Here I have used 'c_' prefix in items for storing cart items for that user

```
class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    body = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/')
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    total_items = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    icon =  models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/')
    c_title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    c_description = models.TextField()
    c_price = models.IntegerField()
    c_total_items = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from products import views as product_views

urlpatterns =[
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('', include('products.urls')),
    path('', product_views.home,name='home'),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `action="post"`, check the method equals `"POST"`, and get the data from `request.POST`.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I update my urls.py now because url pattern matching error is detected on button click.                      
 My urls.py is  
`from products import views as product_views

urlpatterns =[
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('', include('products.urls')),
    path('', product_views.home,name='home'),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`